# make redirect to new url from the old url Magento

Tags: magento, url, redirect, seo, categories

Hi i have a Magento site in which i have a different categories, due to some **reason** i have to **rename** one of the **categories**.

> **Old**  URL  =  www.example.com/wol/schpeege
>
> **New**  URL  =  www.example.com/wol/schpeegewol

for SEO purposes I need to **redirect** the user to

> New **url**

when he enters the

> Old url

Please suggest me how can i do this?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

... or ... use htaccess rewrite rule.
Go to http://seo-website-designer.com/HtAccess-301-Redirect-Generator#heading-ToolResult for creating rule and then save your .htaccess file on your root folder.

Answer (score 0):

Use magento rewrite managment, here is manual http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/urlrewrite/index

Answer (score 0):

You can create URL rewrite for your Requirement.

Here is Step :

1> Login to magento admin
2> Catalog -> URL Rewrite Management -> Create New Url